# Update page when provider receives new data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a provider that retrieves data from the server:

```
setOpciones() {
  this.http.get(this.url, {}, {}).then(response => {
    this.opciones = JSON.parse(response.data);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

getOpciones(){
  return this.opciones;
}
```

In my page, I set a variable that gets printed:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.items = this.data.getOpciones();
}
```

I understand that right now when this.opciones changes that won't affect this.items

How can I make it so it keeps changing?

Comment: Are you keep calling your service in background and the value is getting changed?

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar Yeah, but i also think I have a problem with the delay it takes to get the info from the server. I know how to make it wait inside the provider, but I don't know how to make it wait when I call this.data.getOpciones(); from my page.ts, so I guessed if I can keep both variables in sync I'd solve both problems

Comment: Use `Observable` instead of `Promise` to get more control over the data. You can add delay or hold the data for longer until you unsubscribe it

Answer (score 2):

It's best to set your variables (that are used in the template) in the http callback, as opposed to in the component's lifecycle (ie. ngOnInit). That's the only time you really know you've got the new data.

Also it's generally better to use the Observable/subscribe syntax for http.

For example...

```
setOpciones() {
  this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
    this.opciones = response.data;
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.items = this.data.getOpciones();
}
```

ie. the event that triggers the change (the http response) needs to update the variable (items).

Comment: The thing is that I'm calling the server from a provider and using the data in a page. I can't grasp how to keep the page updated